# How can I get the projects created from kube:admin only, using openshift CLI

Tags: cloud, openshift

I am new to openshift, containers etc and I am doing a workaround a bit.
I managed to create an ARO cluster and I logged in the container platform as well.
I have build a yaml pipeline where I can get a list with all the projects that I have but the thing is that I am also getting the system projects (68 projects).

How can I modify the following command so I could get only the projects that I have created and not the system ones?

oc get projects

thank you.

I have tried to google it a bit but no luck.

Comment: OpenShift project has the annotation which is shown who requested with `openshift.io/requester`. So may be it is good to filter using jq as follows:
```oc get project -o json --as=system:admin | jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.annotations."openshift.io/requester" == "kube:admin") | .metadata.name'```

Comment: Yes, thats a good one. Thank you hiroyukik

Answer (score 0):

if **Log in as a user with cluster-admin** privileges: see

```
admissionConfig:
pluginConfig:
ProjectRequestLimit:
  configuration:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ProjectRequestLimitConfig
    limits:
    - selector:
        level: admin 
    - selector:
        level: advanced 
      maxProjects: 10
    - maxProjects: 2
```

Visit https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_projects.html

I hope it will be fix

Comment: I was wondering if there is a parameter while using the oc get projects command directly in the cli.